# Left Join Get non-matching records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am performing a left join between 2 tables. Assuming both the tables have columns such as id, name and sal, I need to get the matching records plus non-matching records. The jon key is id here. For the non matching records, the sal column should be replaced with 90000, 90001, 90002 etc for each row. So after the join operation is performed, I will be able to identify the non-matching records by the sal column. Can someone help me with the query? 
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far

Comment: What have you tried? This is a pretty simple left join. Maybe you are struggling with the strange replacement requirement?

Answer (score 2):

```
select ta.id,ta.name,
coalesce(tb.sal,
   (row_number() over 
   (partition by tb.sal order by tb.id)) + 89999) sal 
from ta left join tb on ta.id = tb.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    ta.id, 
    ta.name, 
    ISNULL(tb.sal, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by tb.sal order by ta.id) + 89999)
from table_a ta
    left join table_b tb ON tb.id = ta.id
order by ta.id
```